# What does the word 'fully' mean as a noun?

Tags: meaning

Movie *'Half Baked' (1998)* has these two phrases:

> **Fully**, man.

and

> This is an official **fully**.

*Jim Breuer* playing the main (always stoned) character said this while looking at a woman's bare breasts at about 1:13:50 into the movie.

What does *fully* mean as a noun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In contrast to deadrat's answer 'Fully' can be used as slang term for a fully exposed breast popping out (and possibly that breast being large or 'full'). Hence Dave Chappelle's use of the phrase 'Now that's a titty', the guys aren't just commenting because it's any old side boob shot or partial slip but the fact that it is a full blown exposed breast. That being said, I also think out of context the term can mean you fully agree with a statement or point of view etc.

Comment: Almost exactly right, except (at least as I've always heard it used) _full_ here doesn't refer to the size of the breast, but to the completeness of it; that is, the breast slips out, so it's _fully visible_. A fully is thus basically a proper nip slip: a fully visibly breast. (Similar to how a _fully_ is also a fully erect penis, the counterpart to the more commonly used _semi_.) Compare [this UD definition](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fully&defid=1506196).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet great comment will edit to include some of the points you hit on.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs during a fight scene in which one of fighters inadvertently exposes one of her breasts.  One actor comments admiringly "Now, that's a titty!"  Jim Breuer says "Fully, man," meaning that he completely agrees with the assessment of the sight or that the exposure is complete or both.  Likely, what he means to say next is "That is an official *titty*," but he's a stoner so his drugged-out verbal faculties substitute the last word he said that ended with a "y."  And it comes out "That is an official **fully**."

It probably makes more sense if you watch the movie stoned.  In that state, it's also likely that the movie will strike you as amusing.  These are two powerful arguments for just saying "no" to drugs.

Comment: This seems less likely than the slang meaning of _fully_ as a noun, which is basically equivalent to ‘nip slip’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Watch the move stoned and get back to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet what do you estimate are the chances the slang meaning was brought on by the movie?